# Help changing a 2 way 2 gang light switch

Tags: switch, light

[image]I am trying to change a 2 gang 2 way light switch.

The old switch has 5 wires. 2 red wires in the common , L1 brown , L2 white  and L1 blue again
I will try insert a picture of old set up. So I on theft side there is a red common , brown L1 and white L 2 , and the right has a red common and blue L1.

My new switch has 6 wire places. L1^1 , L1 and L1^. And on the right L2^1 , L2 and L2^2

[image: the old switch]
<sup>Click to embiggen</sup>

[image: Back of the new switch]

Comment: Yeah that's the new one just posted the old one , had to do screen shot as it says photo is too large to paste and I have no idea how to change it 

Comment: For the Americans playing along at home the rest of the world counts switch "ways" one lower than you do.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you have brown and "white" on L1 and blue on L2

so from the markings on the back of that switch

> L1<sub>1</sub>   L1 . . L2<sub>2</sub>
>
> L1<sub>2</sub> . . L2 L2<sub>1</sub>

it goes like this:

[image]

Swap the blue wire into the empty L2<sub>2</sub> position if the L2 switch is behaving upside down

The insulation on some of those wires looks very rough,
I'd be considering replacing them ot at-least reinforcing the insulation with a layer of clear (or matching) heat-shrink

Comment: Hey thank you I put it the way you have suggested but the blue is in the top.right thus one was labeled L2¹ and its working as it should be , I put some extra tape around the exposed wires so hopefully all should be good. The joys of an old.house